# What does a cast from malloc return?

Tags: c++, casting, malloc

I am trying to understand what is returned on the last line to name p.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int a;
    int* p;
    p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

Q1
Assuming `malloc(sizeof(int))` returns `&name` (name can be x or y or w),
is it safe to interpret the line as `p=(int*)(memoryAddress to begining of block size)`?

Q2
Can somebody rewrite this to make it more clear? Maybe add a line before p=.. I am a beginner at C++.

This is a link to an image of how I am trying to understand everything...
 this is just for reference
[image]

Comment: Don't use dynamic allocation for a simple variable. Just write `int x;`, or whatever name you want. For dynamic allocation your first choice should be a standard container like `std::vector`; second, for special needs, a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` holding a pointer to memory allocated via a `new`-expression; third, special OS-specific allocation such as Windows' `VirtualAlloc`. Only when a C API requires it, or where you absolutely need the speed from `realloc`, should you use `malloc`. As a beginner you're at the front of this list. I.e. no dynamic allocation, or use std container.

Comment: Q1: There are no names (identifiers) involved, so option B.

Comment: There is no "line 9" in that code.

Comment: trueeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: C or C++? There's nothing specifically C++ about this question.

Comment: @HarmanNieves *I am a beginner at c++.* -- What book or tutorial suggested to you to use `malloc` in a C++ program?  Whatever it is, run away from it.

Comment: So I have found out malloc(sizeof(int) has a return type of void*, and this is the sole reason in the code (int*) is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

This line is simply allocate 4 byte (the actual size is depends on the compiler though) of memory and return the address of first byte. That first byte address is assigned to p.

The return type of malloc is generic (void *). So we need to cast it to int * to use this as integer. By saying "use it as integer", it means that 4 bytes of consecutive memory will be used as one data.

So, if you put a data in that variable as follows:

```
*p=1234
```

It will use all 32 bit memory starting from the memory location stored in p.

Regarding safety, read the comment.

Comment: The size of `int` depends on the system. In practice it can be 1, 2, 4 or 8 bytes (note that a byte is not an octet). Or from 16 to 64 bits.

Comment: The size of the pointer is always the same regardless of type. And this size also depends on the system.

Comment: @OwO -- *The size of the pointer is always the same regardless of type* -- This is not always true.  The sizeof() a pointer to a class member function may not be the same size as a pointer to a non-class member function.

Comment: I am confused. How is 4 bytes accessed as one unit. Isn't everything accessed through the first address of the total row of bytes? Can you explain with regards to the picture I have show of the memory diagram please?

Comment: @HarmanNieves I have edited the answer. Please see if it make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

**I think I have figured it out.**

*Malloc just allocated memory of sizeof(type)
Then it only returns a (void*) and in c++ an int* p cannot be assigned a void* because c++ is strict about "implicit casting".*

*So the answers*

Q1 Answer 
**Assumption is wrong, malloc(sizeof(int)) returns type void* of first byte of number of bytes allocated for sizeof(...)**

Q2 Answer 
**this can be rewritten as**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
int* p;
p = new int;
}
```

Comment: `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` are C headers, and you generally shouldn't be using them in a C++ program.  (Use `<cstdio>` and `<cstdlib>` if you really need the functions they provide, but it's usually preferable to use iostreams instead of stdio,)